# Trazer um Max(Date) com LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho essa *Linq*:

```cs
var resultado = 
(
    from pdv in db.T_PDV
    from tarefa in db.T_TarefaParceiro.Where(trf => trf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from parceiro in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf => prf.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
    from acao in db.T_Acao.Where(ac => ac.IDAcao == tarefa.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from proxima in db.T_ProximaAcao.Where(pxm => pxm.IDAcao == acao.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from info in db.T_InfoClientePdv.Where(inf => inf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from cliente in db.T_Cliente.Where(clie => clie.IDCliente == info.IDCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where pdv.CNPJ == "07599639000184"
    select new
    {
        pdv.CNPJ,
        pdv.DataCadastro,
        cliente.NomeFantasia,
        acao.Acao,
        proxima.ProximaAcao,
        parceiro.NumOs,
        parceiro.DataVisita,
        parceiro.DataAgendamento
})
.ToList()
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Como eu faço nessa linq, trazer o resultado pela maior data. Há um campo chamado `DataVisita` e é por esse campo que eu devo fazer um `Max`, como eu faço?

Comment: deu certo a solução proposta?

Answer (score 4):

Um maneira seria:  um [**Order By Desc**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)  pegando a maior `DataVisita` e chamar o método [**FirstOrDefault()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que escreve na sua SQL um `TOP(1)` (dependendo do banco de dados isso pode mudar, essa instrução SQL é particular do SQL Server):

```
var resultado = 
    (
        from pdv in db.T_PDV
        from tarefa in db.T_TarefaParceiro.Where(trf => trf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from parceiro in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf => prf.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
        from acao in db.T_Acao.Where(ac => ac.IDAcao == tarefa.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from proxima in db.T_ProximaAcao.Where(pxm => pxm.IDAcao == acao.IDAcao).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from info in db.T_InfoClientePdv.Where(inf => inf.CNPJ == pdv.CNPJ).DefaultIfEmpty()
        from cliente in db.T_Cliente.Where(clie => clie.IDCliente == info.IDCliente).DefaultIfEmpty()
        where pdv.CNPJ == "07599639000184"
        order by parceiro.DataVisista descending
        select new
        {
            pdv.CNPJ,
            pdv.DataCadastro,
            cliente.NomeFantasia,
            acao.Acao,
            proxima.ProximaAcao,
            parceiro.NumOs,
            parceiro.DataVisita,
            parceiro.DataAgendamento
    })      
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente o seguinte:

```
var resultado = (
    from pdv in db.T_PDV
    (...)
    where pdv.CNPJ == "07599639000184" &&
    parceiro.DataVisita == (
        from parceiro2 in db.T_OsParceiro.Where(prf2 => prf2.IDTarefaParceiro == tarefa.IDTarefaParceiro)
        select parceiro2.DataVisita).Max()
    select new
    {
        pdv.CNPJ,
        pdv.DataCadastro,
        (...)
    }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer funcionar. Está dando esse erro: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.DateTime'. Tentei de várias formas colocar parêntesis em vários lugares e mesnmo assim continua dando erro.

Comment: Ajustado. Havia colocado '=' ao invés de '==' no operador de igualdade. Vícios de VB.NET :)

Answer (score 0):

Não há nenhum método embutido para fazer isso. Você pode utilizar a lógica de ordenar e obter o primeiro item da lista.

Você pode escrever um método genérico para obter o `Min` ou`Max` para qualquer tipo, passando por parâmetro o elemento a ser ordenado:

```
public static TSource MaxObject<TSource, TComparator>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                      Func<TSource, TComparator> selector)
{
   var result = source.OrderByDescending(selector);
   return result.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Com o seu uso:

```
var maiorObjeto = lista.MaxObject(item => item.Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui eu pego a última data de cadastro de um relógio, usando o `OrderBy` para listar do menor ao maior e pegando a maior data registro com `LastOrDefautl`:

```
var ultimo_relogio= db.Produtos.Where(p=>p.Produtos=="Relogio")
                             .OrderBy(p=>p.data_cadastro).LastOrDefault();
```